# Three JS Phong Material not showing even with Ambient Light on Custom Mesh

Tags: graphics, three.js

Here I'm creating a lined object through forming a Mesh, then applying a MeshPhongMaterial.

Have set my scene, and created a mesh object where I apply the Phong Material to. However the material itself is not evident.

1. Is this potentially due to the way I'm creating vertices? Perhaps there is a complexity in the material (try adding wireframe to view complexity)
2. I have added scene and ambient lighting.

I've made a [demo of this here](https://codepen.io/redrubia/pen/VwPJONL). Here is a snippet of the material itself

```
const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0xFF0000,    // red (can also use a CSS color string here)
    shininess: 150,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    metalness: 0.5,
    emissive: 'red'
});
```

Comment: This material appears bright red to me, which is expected with `emissive: 'red'` on the material. Remove that and you'll see a darker red, and brightening the ambient light brightens that color. Are you expecting something different, and if so what?

Comment: Thanks @DonMcCurdy It appears blck to me. Tried both firefox and chrome thinking it maybe a rendering issue I'm experiencing. I want it to appear shiny as shown in this demo https://threejs.org/docs/scenes/material-browser.html#MeshPhongMaterial

Comment: Hm, that sounds almost like a hardware (e.g. GPU) bug... Do you have a phone or another computer you can test it on? Do the official three.js examples work for you? It might be worth filing a bug on three.js to investigate here, I don't know why we're seeing different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your geometry doesn't have normals, and PhongMaterial needs normals to calculate its color. Simply adding the default `[0, 0, 1]` normal in you `xyzSet()` function renders the red color you're expecting:

```js
g.normals[ posIdx ]  = 0;
g.normals[ posIdx + 1 ]  = 0;
g.normals[ posIdx + 2 ]  = 1.0;
```

[image]